# Why does loss increase when I unfreeze all weights by transfer learing using Tensorflow2

Tags: tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning, loss

[loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy5r7.png)

I have wrapped resnet50 model of tf.keras with some conv layers and dense layers. I used the pre-trained weights from ImageNet

First I trained my model while I freezing weights of resnet50. The loss decreased to a good value. The final lr is 0.0025
Then I unfreeze the weights of resnet50, and started training with a lower lr 0.0001. The loss from beginning is very high. Is the second fit reset the weights?

```
# create a layer to process gray image to 3-channels image
input_shape = IMG_SIZE+(1,)
gray2color_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,1,activation='tanh',input_shape=input_shape)
Rescaling = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(127.5,offset=127.5)
preprocess_res = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input

# create base model(resnet 50)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                                           weights='imagenet', 
                                           # input_shape=(200,200,3),
                                           pooling='avg')

# freeze base model
base_model.trainable = False

# use keras functional API to build the model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape,name='pd') #input tensor
x = gray2color_layer(inputs)
x = Rescaling(x)
x = preprocess_res(x)
x = base_model(x,training=False) # inference mode
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

# callbacks
logdir = "./logs/scalars/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
Call_TensorBoard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
   log_dir=logdir,
   histogram_freq=0,  # How often to log histogram visualizations
   embeddings_freq=0,  # How often to log embedding visualizations
   update_freq="epoch",
) 
Call_EarlyStop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=8)
Call_LR = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5,verbose=1,
                             patience=3, min_lr=0.0001)
Call_LR2 = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5,verbose=1,
                             patience=3, min_lr=0.00001)

# compile
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01), 
             loss=loss_res(var=2),
             metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(),mse_percent()])

# fit
history = model.fit(training_ds,epochs=2,callbacks=[Call_TensorBoard,Call_EarlyStop,Call_LR],validation_data=validation_ds)

# unfreeze weights
base_model.trainable = True

# compile
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001), 
             loss=loss_res(var=2),
             metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(),mse_percent()])

# fit
history_all = model.fit(training_ds,epochs=100,initial_epoch=history.epoch[-1],callbacks=[Call_TensorBoard,Call_EarlyStop,Call_LR2],validation_data=validation_ds)
```

Comment: In the link is the loss from tensorboard

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Transfer learning means that your model starts with very good initializations. It does not mean it will not change any prior information.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal thanks for your answer. But I still don't understand. Since I have same weights when I continue training with unfrozen weights, why the loss will be different with the last epoch I trained with frozen weights.